# Do I need to manually set a WaveMaker LiveForm's dataOutput?

Tags: javascript, wavemaker

I'm setting a LiveForm's `dataSet` manually by grabbing data from a selected grid item. I'm then setting the LiveForm's editors using that data. It looks like this:

```
getCurrentItem: function() {
        var item = this.grid_items.selectedItem.getData().related_item;
        this.liveForm_editItem.setDataSet(item);

        this.item_nameEditor2.setValue("displayValue", item.item_name);
        this.item_nameEditor2.setValue("dataValue", item.item_name);
        this.item_priceEditor2.setValue("displayValue", item.item_price);
        this.item_priceEditor2.setValue("dataValue", item.item_price);
}
```

That function gets attached to the LiveForm's `onBeginUpdate` event so the editors get pre-loaded with data when you go to edit them. This works fine. My problem is that when I try to save the form, the function I've attached to the `onBeforeServiceCall` event is being passed undefined and null. I'm getting this error message:

```
Service Call Failed: .update JsonRpcService.js:410
invalid request; missing method or id: "{"params":[undefined,undefined,null],"method":"update","id":96332}"
```

So I'm wondering, is this an issue with the LiveForm's `dataOutput`? Do I need to set that manually? I'm not sure what values it wants if it wants any at all.

Answer (score 1):

from wavemaker community http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/3703#comment-12466 i quote:

*(To insert data in the database you have)*

> setting the individual widgets in your liveform

```
this.nameEditor1.setDataValue("hello");
this.startDateEditor1.setDataValue(new Date().getTime());
this.empLiveForm.insertData();
```

> Michael Kantor Sr Engineer; WaveMaker

Well, i'm trying to do some similar, if work i would update my answer, but better to check out the link that i posted :)

regards and good luck :)

Edit:

This works, i checkout in wm670

Answer (score 0):

A `LiveForm` is attached to a `LiveVariable`. The `update` function is available for updating the variable, and not the form. 
        `LiveForm` has a method [updateData](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/LiveForms#HMethods).
Now, you can get the entire form's edited values and bundle them in a single variable using `dataOutput` property. I believe this is what you are doing. But the problem *I think* is, you are calling the method `update` , which is for a `LiveVariable`. Hence the error.